# Graphicsmagick convert: Add -border on all 4 sides as percentage of height

Tags: graphicsmagick

When using the -border command I'm able to specify a geometry option which might be

```
-border 10x10
-border 10
-border 2%
-border 2%x2%
```

Now when using percentage values it always is the percent of either the height for top/bottom and width for left/right, which might be different pixel values.

What i want to achieve is to have the same borderwidth as a percentage all around. So i want 2% of the height as border for all 4 sides top/bottom/left/right. Is this possible?
In ImageMagick you can achieve this by using

```
-border x2%
```

but this doesn't work in graphicsmagick. Is something similiar available in graphicsmagick to achieve the same result?